# How to File Upload in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, codeigniter-3

so I'm working in my blog page and I decided to create an input to upload images into a folder located in my assets folder.

So far I've been trying to edit my Post_controller and this is what I got so far:

```
public function add()
{
    // Field Rules
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'trim|required|min_length[3]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('subject_id', 'Subject', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('body', 'Body', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('is_published', 'Publish', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('is_featured', 'Feature', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('order', 'Order', 'integer');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $subject_options = array();
        $subject_options[0] = 'Select Post Category';

        $subject_list = $this->Posts_categories_model->get_list();

        foreach ($subject_list as $subject) {
            $subject_options[$subject->id] = $subject->title;
        }

        $data['subject_options'] = $subject_options;

        // Load template
        $this->template->load('admin', 'default', 'posts/add', $data);
    } else {
        $slug = str_replace(' ', '-', $this->input->post('title'));
        $slug = strtolower($slug);

        // Page Data
        $data = array(
            'title'         => $this->input->post('title'),
            'slug'          => $slug,
            'subject_id'    => $this->input->post('subject_id'),
            'body'          => $this->input->post('body'),
            'is_published' => $this->input->post('is_published'),
            'is_featured'  => $this->input->post('is_featured'),
            'in_menu'      => $this->input->post('in_menu'),
            'user_id'      => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
            'order'        => $this->input->post('order'),
            'post_image'    => $this->upload->do_upload($this->input->post('post_image')),
        );

        // Upload Image
          $data['upload_path'] = './assets/img/posts';
          $data['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
          $data['max_size'] = '2048';
          $data['max_width'] = '2000';
          $data['max_height'] = '2000';

      if(!$this->upload->do_upload($this->input->post('post_image'))){
          $this->input->post('post_image') = './assets/img/posts/noimage.jpg';
      } else {
          $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
          $this->input->post('post_image') = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
      }

        // Insert Page
        $this->Post_model->add($data);

        // Activity Array
        $data = array(
            'resource_id' => $this->db->insert_id(),
            'type'        => 'post',
            'action'      => 'added',
            'user_id'     => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
            'message'     => 'A new post was added (' . $data["title"] . ')'
        );

        // Insert Activity
        $this->Activity_model->add($data);

        // Set Message
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Post has been added');

        // Redirect
        redirect('admin/posts');
    }
}
```

As you can see I created a post_image value which should be uploading the file into the folder but I can not make it work properly, can somebodyu help me?

This is the view where I create the post:

```
<h2 class="page-header">Add Post</h2>
<?php echo validation_errors('<p class="alert alert-danger">'); ?>
<?php echo form_open_multipart('admin/posts/add'); ?>
    <!-- Page Title -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <?php echo form_label('Post Title', 'title'); ?>
        <?php
            $data = array(
                'name' => 'title',
                'id'    => 'title',
                'maxlength' => '100',
                'class'     => 'form-control',
                'value'     => set_value('title')
            );
        ?>
        <?php echo form_input($data); ?>
    </div>

    <!-- Page Img -->
    <div class="form-group">  
        <?php echo form_label('Upload Image', 'post_image') ?>
        <?php form_upload('post_image' , array('class' => 'form-control')); ?>
        <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20">
    </div>

    <!-- Page Subject -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <?php echo form_label('Post Category', 'subject_id'); ?>
        <?php echo form_dropdown('subject_id', $subject_options, 0, array('class' => 'form-control')); ?>
    </div>

    <!-- Page Body -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <?php echo form_label('Body', 'body'); ?>
        <?php
            $data = array(
                'name'          => 'body',
                'id'            => 'body',
                'class'         => 'form-control',
                'value'         => set_value('subject')
            );
        ?>
        <?php echo form_textarea($data); ?>
    </div>

    <!-- Publish -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <?php echo form_label('Published', 'is_published'); ?>
        <?php echo form_radio('is_published', 1, TRUE); ?> Yes 
        <?php echo form_radio('is_published', 0, FALSE); ?> No
    </div>

    <!-- Feature -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <?php echo form_label('Feature', 'is_featured'); ?>
        <?php echo form_radio('is_featured', 1, FALSE); ?> Yes 
        <?php echo form_radio('is_featured', 0, TRUE); ?> No
    </div>

    <!-- Menu -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <?php echo form_label('Add To Menu', 'in_menu'); ?>
        <?php echo form_radio('in_menu', 1, TRUE); ?> Yes 
        <?php echo form_radio('in_menu', 0, FALSE); ?> No
    </div>

    <!-- Order -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <?php echo form_label('Order', 'order'); ?>
        <input class="form-control" name="order" id="order" type="number">
    </div>

    <?php echo form_submit('mysubmit', 'Add Post', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')); ?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
<script>
/*TinyMce editor*/
    tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    theme: "modern",
    image_advtab: true,    
    plugins: [
         "advlist autolink link image lists charmap  preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
         "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime  nonbreaking",
         "table contextmenu directionality template paste textcolor"
            ],
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold underline italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | image link | code fullscreen"
     });
</script>
```

This is my index page in which I want to display them:

```
<?php if($posts) : ?>
    <?php foreach($posts as $page) : ?>
        <div class="featured-page">
            <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>posts/show/<?php echo $page->slug; ?>" class="thumbnail"><h2 class="page-header"><?php echo $page->title; ?></h2></a>
            <!-- Post Image -->
            <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/posts/<?php echo $page->post_image; ?>">
            <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>posts_categories/posts/<?php echo $page->subject_id; ?>"><h2 class="page-header"><?php echo 'Category'; ?></h2></a>
            <?php echo word_limiter($page->body,45); ?>
            <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>posts/show/<?php echo $page->slug; ?>">Read More</a></p>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php else : ?>
    <div class="alert alert-danger">No Post Found</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Where is the problem? What is the error you experience? Try to edit your question and remove not relevant code to this question.

Comment: I have seen quite a few of your questions on this site, and each shows the same amount of effort as the last and there isn't a clear improvement in quality: so and so isn't working, here is a dump of all my code... Please try and troubleshoot more and come back with a succinct question and relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

You didnt echo your form upload in view file.

Add ECHO in your form_upload method.

```
<?php echo form_upload('post_image' , array('class' => 'form-control')); ?>
```

and remove the html file upload since you dont need it

```
<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20">
```

at the validation of form upload at your CONTROLLER just simply say

```
$this->upload->do_upload('post_image')
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, `do_upload` expects the *name* of the file input.

Secondly, often in your code you are doing `$this->input->post('post_image')` this will return *nothing* as an image or file is in the `$_FILES` array not the `$_POST` array.

Thirdly, you need to initialize the upload library with your config! `$this->load->library('upload', $someconfig)`

So after all this your code should look like:

```
        $slug = str_replace(' ', '-', $this->input->post('title'));
        $slug = strtolower($slug);

        // Upload Image
        $upload['upload_path'] = './assets/img/posts';
        $upload['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $upload['max_size'] = '2048';
        $upload['max_width'] = '2000';
        $upload['max_height'] = '2000';

        $this->load->library('upload', $upload);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('post_image')) {
            // in view you do this:  base_url()/assets/img/posts/ no need for full string here just filename
            $filename = 'noimage.jpg';
            // or leave blank and sort it out in your view with empty($page->post_image) ? 'noimage.jpg' : $page->post_image (better approach)
        } else {
            $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
            $filename = $upload_data['file_name'];
        }

        // Page Data
        $data = array(
            'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
            'slug' => $slug,
            'subject_id' => $this->input->post('subject_id'),
            'body' => $this->input->post('body'),
            'is_published' => $this->input->post('is_published'),
            'is_featured' => $this->input->post('is_featured'),
            'in_menu' => $this->input->post('in_menu'),
            'user_id' => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
            'order' => $this->input->post('order'),
            'post_image' => $filename
        );

        // Insert Page
        $this->Post_model->add($data);

        // Activity Array
        $data = array(
            'resource_id' => $this->db->insert_id(),
            'type' => 'post',
            'action' => 'added',
            'user_id' => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
            'message' => 'A new post was added (' . $data["title"] . ')'
        );

        // Insert Activity
        $this->Activity_model->add($data);

        // Set Message
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Post has been added');

        // Redirect
        redirect('admin/posts');
```

Also please take into account the other answerers notes, they are valid regarding echoing your fileinput.

`<?php echo form_upload('post_image' , array('class' => 'form-control')); ?>` and remove the input with userfile